# Activesync connection between two USB-host controllers

Tags: networking, usb, windows-mobile, windows-ce, activesync

For a hobby project I wish to develop some stuff for a WinCE 6.0 device. Ideally, I would have an activesync connection to debug from Visual Studio. The OS appears to have all the prerequisites in place, but I'm not sure about the transport. What are my options?

The device has a USB port which can be used to connect e.g. flash drives for mp3 playback, so this seems to be a USB host port. Can I use this to obtain an activesync connection? I guess using a usb-to-serial cable on both pc and WinCE device could work. Or is there a RNDIS way perhaps?

If possible I rather not disassemble the unit, but if my chances of finding a USB client port or wired ethernet are nonzero I could consider that. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ActiveSync will work on a serial cable, so the idea of using an USB-to-serial adapter may work. But you need to have drivers for it in the OS image. There are some CDC drivers and FTDI provides drivers for their chips. You may be able to load them on the device, copying them using a USB thumbdrive and modifying the registry using a registry editor for windows CE, but that's not granted. Windows CE also supports RNDIS compatible USB to ethernet adapter but honestly I don't know if any device of this kind is currently available on the market. If your device has wi-fi connectivity you can skip using ActiveSync and debug over the network.

Answer (score 1):

You **can not** use `USB host port` for `Activesync` connection.

But if it is `USB OTG` (Both `host` and `client`) port, you can use `activesync` using `USB OTG` or `USB Client` functionality.

Your BSP should support `USB Serial Client` functionality (Search `SYSGEN_USBFN_SERIAL` sysgen variable in `catalog items`).

Also, your `USB driver` (lower level driver) should support `USB Client` functionality.

Comment: Clearly connecting two USB host ports will not work. I found that the board also seems to contain a JTAG connector. Could that be used for ActiveSync debugging? Also, I found that the USB chip is a SMSC USB2514B which has 4 ports. I'll find out if perhaps one of them is already configured in client mode in the BSP.

Comment: `I found that the board also seems to contain a JTAG connector. Could that be used for ActiveSync debugging?` No, AFAIK, there is no way to use `JTAG` for `ActiveSync` connection.

`USB chip is a SMSC USB2514B which has 4 ports. I'll find out if perhaps one of them is already configured in client mode in the BSP` Yes, You can check this out...